# Auto-Logout with multiple tabs open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, logout

we've implemented a system similar to the one described in this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709182/asp-net-implementing-auto-logout-functionality). Basically, if the user doesn't do anything for 14 minutes, we prompt them that they will be logged out. If they click on "keep me logged in" we do an ajax request to keep their session alive, otherwise, they are redirected to the logout page after a minute.

It works pretty well, and is inline with similar systems employed at sites like mint.com and bankofamerica.com. The only problem is that our application's users tend to have multiple tabs open to refer back and forth to different pieces of data. So the problem is that they may be actively working in one tab, but then the other tab times out and logs them out. This causes an abrupt session timeout for the user when they were not expecting it. btw, mint.com has this same issue.

So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas to combat this?

I have one idea, each request could set a "last active time" cookie. Upon auto-logout, the server could check this last active time and if it's relatively recent, avoid logging them out. The manual logout would of course ignore this cookie so if the user wants to log out he can do so at any time. However, I'm afraid that this may be exposing some sort of security risk that I'm not able to see at this point. Thoughts?

Comment: I know it is a long time ago this has been posted, however just came across it and had the idea: if a user has multiple instances open, and the 14 minutes are over, the pop-up will show in all instances. You could at this time check every x seconds (for this one minute till the user is going to be signed out), if they have already clicked "keep me logged in" (also best via ajax). The problem I see if you just check the last time active, is that once those pop up shows and the user dismisses it in one tab, they will still be signed out after a minute due to the refer to logout from another tab.

Comment: Just add one more step, @Chris: check the server to see if they've reupped before logging out. Log them out if they haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before showing the pop-up, ask the server how long ago the user has done his last request.

Comment: We don't currently store the last request time ... although, perhaps if we invert the problem. If we set that cookie for each request, and then as you suggest just check it before we show the timeout dialog. That way, we're not adding any code to the server per se. Interesting, do you think this could work and be secure?

Comment: If an attacker can read the cookies, he already has access to the authentication cookie and he is in the system. So this cookie does not make it less secure.