# Asp.net login control Autologout/AutoRedirect and label Value

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, login-control

I have setup an asp.net login control (the provided control from asp.net configuration) and it's working fine.

I have added code to the web.config, so that after 3 min, it automatically logs out the user.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!-- Autologout after xxx min. to login.aspx -->
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="3"/>
</authentication>
```

If using that code, then I get the autologout and if clicking on a link after 3 min then I get to the login page.

How does this work?  Is it 3 min from login or is it after 3 min of inactivity !?

Also, can I add a label on my login page and then it will tell the user why he/she is redirected to the login page, if YES how ?

And lastly: how can i get it to redirect the user to the login page after 3 min. so it's not after 3 min. and then when the user clicks a link, but so it's after 3 min, refresh (if inactivity) and then automatically jump to the login page and show my label with text, explaining why he/she is not logged in !??

............................................................................................................................................................................

I cant get it to work if we look at the no. 2 solution.

On my main page (code_behind) i have this in page_load Session("logintime") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
with a response write i get this on main page 01-10-2012 18:30:42, now its 18:37:25 and it haven't redirect yet, and i haven't made activity in the prowser window at all.

My code for the main page is.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 30000
var timeLoggedIn = new Date('<%=Session("logintime")%>')
var timeLogOut = new Date('<%=Session("logoutTime") %>');

setTimeout(LoggedInCheck(), 30000);

function LoggedInCheck() {
    var now = new Date();
    var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    if (now_utc > timeLogOut) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.dk";
    }
}

function countDown() {
    if (count <= 0) {
       // window.location = redirect;
    } else {
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "This page will redirect in " + count + " seconds."
        setTimeout("countDown()", 1000)
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<span id="timer">  
<script>
countDown();
</script>  
</span> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code_behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Session("logintime") = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        Session("logoutTime") = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

        Response.Write("time now: " & Session("logintime"))
        Response.Write("<br />")
        Response.Write("reload at time: " & Session("logoutTime"))
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution.

In web.config add.

```
<sessionState timeout="3"></sessionState>
```

remember its working in min.

On the page u need to test for the autologout use this in code_behind, to start the javascript.

```
Partial Class _default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "onLoad", "DisplaySessionTimeout()", True)
        Response.Write(Session.Timeout)
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

U dont need the response.write its just for testing that it get the right session.timeout from web.config in min.

On ur main page use this code, (u dont need the counter her, its just for testing so u know when its redirecting u)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
    var count = 60 * sessionTimeout
    function DisplaySessionTimeout() {
        setTimeout("location.href='http://www.google.com';", 60000 * sessionTimeout);
    }

    function countDown() {
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "This page will redirect in " + count + " seconds."
        setTimeout("countDown()", 1000)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<span id="timer">  
<script>
countDown();
</script>  
</span> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here its taking the session.timeout and * it with 60000 mili. sec. so it after 3 min. will redirect to the login page or in this case google.

I havent got the time to test it with a gridview to see if its reset the counter, when the session.timeout is reset bc of activity, so u need to test that, but here is a working code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx) on `SlidingExpiration`:

> Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the timeout interval has elapsed. If the cookie expires, the user must re-authenticate.

So you can say it's after 3' of inactivity.

Re. the auto-logout message, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709182/asp-net-implementing-auto-logout-functionality) and its answer(s) can give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store preferably in a session perhaps the time the user logged in then evaluate on that.  You can also use a cookie to expire your time.

Alternatively you could look into the JavaScript >> http://jsfiddle.net/F8umt/3/

But you should store the time the user logged in.  Your from my understanding your script may be refreshing every time the user does a task that resets the login counter.  You need to basically create a logged in time then determine from it.

I have updated the code and tested it and it appears to work fine on my machine.  The problem was is that Date.Parse casted it incorrectly so I changed it code slightly.  Please Vote if this works for you.

Also Possibly Redirect to a Page that kills the session and cookie before bouncing them to the LogIn Page again otherwise this code will not work as well.

Comment: im sry to say it, but its not reloading automatic, see my main question, for cde i have now, i have a page with these 2 text, and after 6 min. its still the same text. time now: 03-10-2012 10:20:11
reload at time: 03-10-2012 10:23:11

Comment: Hi Deano, its not reloading after the 3 min. if i delete the session, where it get the date and so on, and just add a simple settimeout, then its working, have added a counter so i know when it will reload, but nothing happens after the 3 min. the counter is just running in a loop, so its starting from 30000 when getting to 0,   see main question for new code.

Comment: Hi,  I only provided code to point you in the right direction.  My samples work as described.  it is because you are more than likely moving the page that is resetting the sessions again.  Another idea is to look into the SetTimeOut.  I cannot continue to help with code as the answer is rather obvious at this stage.

Comment: Ok, I now have tested themselves and talked with a number of other who says that the code will never be able to work, and that it is  cannot Check Either time is higher or lower on that way, and it must also be said that when you make an alert timeLogOut or on timeLoggedIn it is an Alert error, but am I doing an alert on now_utc, then it throw the date to me from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one first approach is that, when the user try to access to a restricted page and he can't access due an automatic logout, the server put him in the login page but with a POST variable called ReturnURL. You can `Try` to read this varible and, if not `Nothing`, you *could* think that the user is there because an automatic logout...