# Session management in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, session, session-timeout

Im new developer in asp.net. I want to make a Session management that if 10 minutes passes without any action, the system will end the session and logout the user.

I searched about it and I found this code:

In Web.config file:

```
<sessionState
   mode="InProc"
   cookieless="true"
   timeout="10" />
```

And in the page we want to end the session:

```
public int Timeout { get; set; }
```

But when I tried it, it didn't work!
I don't not know should I try it in a server rather than localhost or this code does not satisfy the purpose that I need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709182/asp-net-implementing-auto-logout-functionality

Comment: Note that session expiration doesn't necessarily have anything to do with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page

{

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)

{

base.OnPreRender(e);

AutoRedirect();

}

public void AutoRedirect()

{

int int_MilliSecondsTimeOut = (this.Session.Timeout * 60000);

string str_Script = @"

<script type='text/javascript'>

intervalset = window.setInterval('Redirect()'," + int_MilliSecondsTimeOut.ToString() + @");

function Redirect()

{

alert('Your session has been expired and system redirects to login page now.!\n\n');

window.location.href='/login.aspx';

}

</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", str_Script);

}

}
```

Read more [How to do auto logout and redirect to login page when session expires using asp.net?](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource9-how-to-do-auto-logout-and-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires-using.aspx)

[Auto redirect to login page when Session is expired](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Auto-redirect-to-login-e1782b2f)

Comment: Useful link ! thumbs up. the best answer,.and sorry I can't vote for your answer because of my low reputations. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in page load

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
Authentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: what namespase should I include for" Authentication.SignOut();"
?

Comment: use FormsAuthentication and add namespace using System.Web.Security;