# How to set property in master page from class in app_code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

How do I set a property in a master page from a class in app_code?

my master page:

```
private int styleGroup;
public int StyleGroup
{
    get { return styleGroup; }
    set { styleGroup = value; }
}
```

how to I set StyleGroup from a class in the app_code?
something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
currentPage.Master.StyleID = 5;
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495245/how-do-i-reference-an-asp-net-masterpage-from-app-code

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the MasterPage of current to you MasterPage Class, something like this

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
((YourMasterPageClass)currentPage.Master).StyleID = 5;
```

Comment: How can I inherit the Master page class? because if do it your way it says 'the type or name space name SiteMaster could not be found'
SiteMaster is my master page class.

Comment: Your Master Page class must be 'Site', that Inherits from MasterPage, so you should put something like:


[VB]
`Dim Master As Site = DirectCast(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page).Master, Site)
Master.StyleGroup=5`


[C#]
`Site Master = (Site)((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).Master;
Master.StyleGroup=5;`

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Page pointer to the app_code class function or set a Page member in the class in app_code.