# Calling a Function in MasterPage code behind from App_Code .cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I have a file in the `App_Code` file which is some legacy code, that I use to control Login and sessions. Ideally, once I am logged in, I wish to update the ..Master.cs to fire a function to update the layout (some panels, become enabled etc).

I can access `App_Code` easily from Code Behind, though I'm unable to figure out how to do this the other way round.

MasterPage.master.cs (code behind)

```
 public static class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage{
      ...
      public static void LogInCB{
        //stufff
      }
      ...
  }
```

App_Code (something.cs)

```
 public static string(){

     //Master.LogInCB();     -tried
     //System.Web.UI.MasterPage.LogInCB();      -tried
     return something;
}
```

I'm happy to accept links to official MS documents on things about this.

Answer (score 1):

The code-behind doesn't know what master page you are using. One way to fix this is to cast the `Page.Master` as your master page class. Once you do that, it will intellisense available functions:

```
YourNameSpace.MasterPage m = (YourNameSpace.MasterPage)Page.Master;
m.LogInCB();
```

Comment: I am not using a Namespace in my MasterPage; when adding one it also seems to invalidate my control references. for example

    button1.enabled = false;

would now error as button1 could not be found. I also assume that I am missing some for of reference. 

It would also error:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Master.get'

Comment: What happens then if you just use `MasterPage m = (MasterPage)Page.Master`? Assuming that it understands you mean your `MasterPage` and not `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. You probably will need to remove `static` from `LogInCB` as well.

Comment: Ahh I get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Master.get'`   I am not sure;

I changed my Master file,  `namespace MasterOne
{
    public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {`

Comment: I wasn't considering the implications of being in the App_Code folder. [This post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495245/how-do-i-reference-an-asp-net-masterpage-from-app-code).